# Why will this program not sort the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am aware that there is a sort function available in C# to sort arrays into the correct order, but for reasons, I need to do it with my own code.

I have come up with this, and some of the numbers move, but it never fully sorts.  Has anyone any idea why?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arraySort = { 2, 5, 7, 3, 6, 3 };
        int save;
        bool sorted = false;

        while(sorted == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (arraySort.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                sorted = true;
                if (arraySort[i] > arraySort[i + 1])
                {
                    save = arraySort[i];
                    arraySort[i] = arraySort[i + 1];
                    arraySort[i + 1] = save;
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySort.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arraySort[i]);
        }
    }
```

My output ends up being:

> 2 3 5 3 6 7

Comment: sorted = true; mis-placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `sorted = true` inside the for loop.

So it stops as soon as the penultimate entry is less than the final entry. All other checks are ignored when validating the outer loop

Answer (score 2):

You set sorted=true every item you iterate,
You need to do sorted=true outside of the for loop, between the while and the for.

```
while (sorted == false) {
            sorted = true;// here seems like the right place!
            for (int i = 0; i < (arraySort.Length - 1); i++)
            {     
                if (arraySort[i] > arraySort[i + 1])
                {
                    save = arraySort[i];
                    arraySort[i] = arraySort[i + 1];
                    arraySort[i + 1] = save;
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do:

```
arraySort = arraySort.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Because... he stated in his question, that for reasons he didn't want to go into, he needs to do this in his own code, as opposed to a quick one-line solution.